# How to protect domain socket file

Tags: linux, sockets, unix

I'm having 2 apps that communicate via unix domain socket on linux.
After running the apps, I see a file corresponding to the socket path name was created in file system.

Then I tried with a scenario as below:

1. Start server app, server is listening now
2. Delete the file that created by above server from terminal
3. Start the client app.

The result was: server still listens forever, and client failed to connect to server.

My question: Is there any way to protect the socket file from being removed while it is in used (e.g: hide it completely from other processes, or lock it until the owner release the lock)?

Comment: Your file was not deleted. No file is ever deleted while it's in use. What was deleted is its directory entry. There is no mechanism to protect directory entries from deletion other than the normal permissions mechanism.

Comment: If the server process execs the client process, you can use `socketpair()` to set up an anonymous Unix socket in much the same way you'd use `pipe()` (except the socket is two-way and can be a datagram or stream, not a one-way stream like pipes).